# How to create a function with .httpAuth in helper.js

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to create a one login function that accepts user name and password of Auth Dialog using `.httpAuth` in `helper.js` in TestCafe. How I can create the function so that I can use it wherever the login is required.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `.httpAuth` method can be used as a method of [`fixture`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/fixture/httpauth.html) or [`test`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/test/httpauth.html).

If I understand you correctly, you want to use some imported `{username, password}` object with [HTTP Autentication](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html#http-authentication).

It can be reached by using import from a helper file:

**authHelper.js**

```js
const authCredentials = {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
}

export default authCredentials;
```

**test-1.js**

```js
import auth from './authHelper'

fixture `My fixture 1`
    .page `http://example.com`
    .httpAuth(auth);

test('Test1', async t => {}); // Logs in as username
```

**test-2.js**

```js
import auth from './authHelper'

fixture `My fixture 2`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test
    .httpAuth(auth)
    ('Test1', async t => {}); // Logs in as username
```

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please ["accept" this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?